# Is it possible to use the `a = b or c` construct if b and c are arrays/DataFrames in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is about the following type of statement:

```
b = np.array([1,2,3,4])

def func(a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = b
```

which I would like to replace the if statement with:

```
def func(a=None):
    a = a or b
```

so firstly two things: I can't do the above as an argument default because I need the default value to be evaluated at runtime (i.e if the default value is actually an object attribute that is expected to change). Secondly, I heard that maybe the way I want to do it is not always recommended by convention, but I'm just asking from a more hypothetical perspective how to make the above work. So far I've always been writing it the first way, but in my honest opinion the second feels better.

`a = a or b` above fails because in this case, `a` is expected to be an array or `pandas.DataFrame`, so it gives me the standard `truth value of an array is ambiguous` error. It would work if `a` and `b` were floats for example.

So is there some way to write the above similarly to how I'm doing (and concisely), but to use the fact that arrays/lists of non-zero length are evaluated as true in python (i.e it would work if `a` was a list for example?

Comment: `return a if bool(a) else b`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That would raise the same error.

Comment: `a if a is not None else b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tertiary operator and compute the truth value yourself. Assuming `a` is an array for example:

```
a = a if a is not None and all(a) else b
```

where you can replace the truth logic if you like.

Comment: This'll throw an error if no argument is provided and `a` assumes its default `None` value.

Comment: True, need to check for `None` first if the default argument is not set.

Comment: That still throws an error for multi-dimensional arrays, and more importantly I don't think that's the behavior the OP wants. Just `a = a if a is not None else b` is fine.

Comment: Well that is why the truth logic would be replaced, I just point out a template, you can't assume the array is of any dimension, or any boolean reduction and we don't what the dataframe looks like.

Comment: Just a question, what's the all(a) for, I didn't understand that part? But actually the 'a is not None' seems like exactly what I need for the runtime default part.

Comment: That is if `a` is an array you would like some other logic like if it is an array of 0s, you might not want to use it assume it is false.

Comment: Right, thanks for the answer, I upvoted earlier. For my purposes just the None part works fine but I see what you mean.